# `Symbol.iterator` that yields Object's values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator

I wrote this

```js
myObj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3,
};

myObj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (let val of Object.values(this))
        yield val;
};

for(let x of myObj)
    console.log(x);  // 1,2,3
```

This works, but looks unnecessary verbose to me. Is there a way to express the same in a more direct way? Basically, what I'm looking for is a simple expression that says "this object's iterator is its values iterator". I tried

```
myObj[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
    return Object.values(this)[Symbol.iterator]
}
```

which didn't work.

Comment: You didn't actually call the `[Symbol.iterator]` *method*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.values(this)[Symbol.iterator]` is a function which returns an iterator. Instead of returning the function, you should return the result of calling it (the iterator):

```js
const myObj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
};

myObj[Symbol.iterator] = () => Object.values(myObj)[Symbol.iterator]();

for (const x of myObj)
  console.log(x); // 1,2,3
```

You can also create a separate function, which will work with any object:

```js
const myObj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
};

const iterator = function() {
  return Object.values(this)[Symbol.iterator]();
};

myObj[Symbol.iterator] = iterator;

for (const x of myObj)
  console.log(x); // 1,2,3
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that possible without a wrapper function?  `myObj[Symbol.iterator] = Object.values(myObj)[Symbol.iterator]` doesn't work.

Comment: @georg `Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator].bind(Object.values(myObj))`, but notice that this calls `Object.value` immediately, not at the time of iteration

Comment: @georg I don't think so; but you can create separate function which will work with any object (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

Nearly, you need to [call the iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator) and use [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) for returning the values of another iterator.

```js
myObj = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };

myObj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield* Object.values(this);
};

for(let x of myObj)
    console.log(x);  // 1,2,3
```

Comment: Thanks, `yield star` is a good idea, always forget about this syntax...